# Issue using Python PIL/pillow to resize image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I have read a data array into pillow via the `Image.fromarray` method. While I am able to bring it into pillow and successfully paste it onto another image in memory, `img.resize((1920,1080))` and `img,thumbnail((1920, 1080))` have no effect (and no error).

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this operations create copies affected by the corresponding transformation. Have you tried `img = img.resize((1920, 1080))`?

Comment: That was it! Ugh I was stuck for hours. I will update the title and question to reflect this answer.